# Slick Slider: недостаточно слайдов для прокрутки

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slick.js

Есть slick-слайдер с параметрами `slidesToShow: 3, slidesToScroll: 1`. Если слайдов больше трёх, то всё работает корректно:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1500,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
})
```

```css
.slide {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
</div>
```

Но если оставить только три слайда, пропадают элементы управления и прокрутка блокируется:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1500,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
})
```

```css
.slide {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</div>
```

Можно ли заставить slick-слайдер прокручивать то количество слайдов, которое дано к показу? Или придётся использовать другой слайдер?

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать при недостатке слайдов клонировать имеющиеся и добавить их в слайдер

```js
$('.slider').on('init reInit',function(e,slick){
  if(slick.slideCount<=slick.options.slidesToShow){
    slick.slickAdd(slick.$slides.clone())
  }
})
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
})
```

```css
.slide {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вариант интересный, спасибо! Есть в нём, правда, один недостаток - при dots: true количество точек в два раза больше чем нужно =))

Comment: @humster_spb , угу. Можно конечно css-ом скрыть лишние `li`, но это уже явной костыльщиной отдаёт